# How I schedule the starting and stopping of a Google Server?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server-2012

I have a virtual machine with Windows server 2012 on google server (like amazon EC2).

How can I configure the Google machine for work:

- Monday to Friday 08:00 am to 18:00 pm machine on...
- Saturday and Sunday machine off